# How to find matches for a row in a dataframe conditional on many rows from another dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function which goes through each row of one database, and compares the values in this dataframe to the values of all the rows in another dataframe and finds which rows match/do not match. I think an example would better explain:

Dataframe 1

```
chr pos
1 150
1 225
2 150 
3 600
```

Dataframe 2

```
chr start stop 
1 100 200
1 250 300
2 100 300
3 50 150 
3 500 700
```

Desired output

```
chr pos 
1 225
```

The idea is that one-by-one each line in df1 is evaluated against every line in df2. In each evaluation the chr must match exactly, and then the pos value from df1 must fall outside the range of the start stop values for each given line in df2. I appreciate this is a wordy problem, but essentially I want a way to find which rows in df1 do not fit into any of the ranges in df2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking at df1 values to be compared with df2 ranges, I would first perform a `left_join`. Consequently, it is easy to check if pos is outside the range (i.e. lower than start or greater than stop)

```
df1 <- data.frame(chr = c(1,1,2,3), pos = c(150, 225, 150, 600))
df2 <- data.frame(chr = c(1,1,2,3,3), start = c(100, 250, 100, 50, 500), stop = c(200, 300, 300, 150, 700))

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("chr")) %>% 
  filter(pos < start | pos > stop) %>% 
  select(chr, pos)
```

Comment: Performing a left_join will multiply out the rows with matching chromosomes, so I will still end up with each row being evaluated correct? I can't believe I didn't think of such a simple solution, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` to go over all rows of `df1` and test them if they fit in `df2`. The resulting index can be used to subsest those of `df1` who don not fit in `df2`.

```
df1[unlist(sapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i) {
  idx  <- df1$chr[i] == df2$chr
  if(!any(df1$pos[i] >= df2$start[idx] & df1$pos[i] <= df2$stop[idx])) i else NULL
})),]
#  chr pos
#2   1 225
```

Or you use `findInterval`

```
do.call(rbind, sapply(unique(df1$chr), function(i) {
  idx1 <- df1$chr == i
  idx2 <- df2$chr == i
  ii  <- findInterval(df1$pos[idx1], c(t(df2[idx2, c("start", "stop")]))) %% 2 == 0
  if(any(ii)) {df1[idx1,][ii,]
  } else {NULL}
}))
#  chr pos
#2   1 225
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using non-equi anti-join in `data.table`:

```
df1[!df2, on=.(chr, pos>start, pos<stop)]
```

output:

```
   chr pos
1:   1 225
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- fread("chr pos
1 150
1 225
2 150 
3 600")
df2 <- fread("chr start stop 
1 100 200
1 250 300
2 100 300
3 50 150 
3 500 700")
```