# Is it possible to merge based on many conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to compare the data based on a date and if the date is between the range then take the lowest "PDF2" value.

This is an example of the two dataframe I'm working with. I want to check if the data of the column "R" from "df" is found in the column "R" of "df2" check if the date is between the range of df2 and if there is any conflict or duplicate I want to always keep the lowest value of "PDF2".

```
df <- data.frame("D" = c("01/01/2019", "01/02/2019", "01/03/2019", "01/12/2019"),
             "R" = c("ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC1"),
             "PDF" = c(1.23, 1.23, 1.23, 1.23),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame("DD" = c("01/01/2019", "01/02/2019", "01/01/2019"),
              "DF" = c("01/02/2019", "01/03/2019", "01/11/2019"),
              "R" = c("ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC1"),
              "PDF2" = c(1.12, 1.11, 1.12),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This is the result I'm expecting.

```
result <- data.frame("R" = c("ABC123", "ABC123", "ABC123"),
                 "D" = c("01/01/2019", "01/02/2019", "01/03/2019"),
                 "DD" = c("01/01/2019", "01/02/2019", "01/02/2019"),
                 "DF" = c("01/02/2019", "01/03/2019", "01/03/2019"),
                 "PDF" = c(1.23, 1.23, 1.23),
                 "PDF2" = c(1.12, 1.11, 1.11),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

As you can see the "ABC1" isn't in the result because the date isn't in the range.

My current problem is to only keep the lowest value if there are duplicate or conflict for the date range.

Here is a sample of my current code :

```
temp <- merge(df, df2, by = "R")
myd <- which(as.Date(temp$D, format = "%d/%m/%Y") <= as.Date(temp$DF, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
myd2 <- which(as.Date(temp$D, format = "%d/%m/%Y") >= as.Date(temp$DD, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
myd <- myd[myd %in% myd2]
if (length(myd)) {
  temp <- temp[myd,]
}
```

And also how can I get the lines that didn't match the requirements in a separate dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answers to this question might help you:

[How to find matches for a row in a dataframe conditional on many rows from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071938/how-to-find-matches-for-a-row-in-a-dataframe-conditional-on-many-rows-from-anoth/59072096#59072096)

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "R") %>% 
  filter(lubridate::dmy(D) >= lubridate::dmy(DD) & lubridate::dmy(D) <= lubridate::dmy(DF)) %>% 
  group_by(R,D) %>% 
  filter(PDF2 == min(PDF2)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my data frame is actually different from the one I showed, so do I simply need to change the group_by() or is there other things to change for your solution to work perfeclty ?

Comment: Because when I run your code and adapt the name of my current dataframe I get this warning :
Warning messages:
1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: This is probably due to the parsing of date formats by `lubridate`. Wat format are your dates? `lubridate::dmy` assumes "d-m-y" (e.g. 01/01/2019) formats.

Comment: My date was in the right format it just that my column names have space and first i put this "" but then realise I had to use this one ``.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `data.table` package if you want something very efficient. The following code would do what you ask for

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df, key="R")
setDT(df2, key="R")

df[, D:=as.Date(D, format = "%d/%m/%Y")]
df2[, `:=`(
  DD = as.Date(DD, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
  DF = as.Date(DF, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
)]

df[df2][D>=DD & D<=DF][, .(DD=max(DD), DF=max(DF), PDF2=PDF2[which.max(DD)]), .(D, R, PDF)]
##              D      R  PDF         DD         DF PDF2
##  1: 2019-01-01 ABC123 1.23 2019-01-01 2019-02-01 1.12
##  2: 2019-02-01 ABC123 1.23 2019-02-01 2019-03-01 1.11
##  3: 2019-03-01 ABC123 1.23 2019-02-01 2019-03-01 1.11
```